Job is added to queue but is not run by Laravel
I need to run the job through the queue. So this is where I call dispatch:
try {
            importProductsFromPlatform::dispatch($api, $options);
            // dispatch(new importProductsFromPlatform($api, $options));
        } catch (\Throwable $th) {
            $txt = "\n".'dispatching error: '.print_r($th->getMessage(), true);
            file_put_contents(storage_path('logs/import_products.log'), $txt.PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
        }

And this is the "job" class:
    namespace App\Jobs;

use App\Models\ApiClient;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldBeUnique;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class importProductsFromPlatform implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected ApiClient $api;
    protected $options = null;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(ApiClient $api, $options = null)
    {
        $this->api = $api;
        $this->options = $options;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $txt = "\n".'handling import, options: '.print_r($this->options, true);
        file_put_contents(storage_path('logs/import_products.log'), $txt.PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
        $this->api->helper()->parse_remote_products($this->options);
    }
}

This handle method is never called, because the log entry is not created (log entries from other places in code work fine). However if after dispatching I implement command php artisan queue:work --once the job gets done.
So what am I doing wrong? How can I get the job done without terminal command?

You need to use a program such as Supervisor to run the php artisan queue:work command for you. https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/queues#supervisor-configuration

do you have the job in your kernel?  when you do php artisan schedule:list appears?

@francisco Yes, there is a task in kernel that runs jobs in queue every hour or so, but I need this job to be implemented at once. As soon as I dispatch it.

@ArunAS So job will not run on its own? It needs to be run only by command?

@KirillOzeritski job will not run on its own. When you dispatch a job, it will be saved into the queue ( redis, sqs, database, etc ), think of the queue as a database. The php artisan queue:work command will read jobs from the queue and execute them

If you use QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync, you won't need the queue:work command. But that is because the sync connection is the same as not using the queue, the job gets executed immediately without being saved to the queue, so it could slow down the response

Thanks to Arun I got my jobs executed. For this I only ran this command once php artisan queue:listen and now every job that is added to queue is implemented at once.
Btw my QUEUE_CONNECTION is sync but it did not run without a command.
